# How can I use a typedef struct from one module as a global variable in another module?

Tags: c, module, global-variables

I am learning C and I am having some trouble with a bit of homework I was given.

I am attempting to use a linked list that I have implemented as part of one header inside of another header. My implementation of the list includes a `typedef` that looks like this:

```
typedef struct queue_T
{
    int count;
    struct member_T * first;
    struct member_T * last;
} * queue_T;
```

The above `typedef` is inside of one source file (`.c`). I am currently attempting to write a second source file that makes use of this type. Inside this source file, I attempted to declare some `queue_T` variables for use as global variables. I did so like this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include "mathfns.h"
#include "queue.h"

queue_T primes;
queue_T squares;
queue_T cubes;

primes = new_queue();
squares = new_queue();
cubes= new_queue();
```

`new_queue()` is my initializer function for the queue_T type and `mathfns.h` is the header file associated with the source file that you're looking at immediately above this paragraph. The above declarations of queue_T variables are defaulting to integers when I attempt to compile and when I attempt to initialize the variables it is generating an error. How can I avoid this? Should I `#include` the"`queue.h` header in the `mathfns.h` file

Thank you.

Comment: There's no such thing as a module in C. You have header files (`.h`) that contain function prototypes, possibly some `extern` variable declarations, macros etc; you include these in your source files (`.c`). You should show us `queue.h` and `mathfns.h` (the entire files).

Comment: Sorry, my professor referred to the combination of the .c and .h file as a "module", so I assumed that was the correct terminology. I'll update the question.

Comment: You can use types declared in one header in any source file that includes that header, or (not recommended) by copying the type declaration.  You cannot, however, perform function calls outside of a function.  The problem with the code you presented is your attempt to initialize global variables `primes`, `squares`, and `cubes` by calling `new_queue()`.

Comment: Also, it is poor form to hide pointer nature behind a typedef, as your `queue_T` type does.

Comment: Thanks for the help, John. I'm new to this website as well, is there a way I can give you credit for this answer?

Comment: @MatthewHelmer, I am in the process of writing an actual answer to the question.  Once I post it, you will have the option to "accept" it (or someone else's, if another is posted that you like better).

Comment: Also, as a follow up, if I were to write a function whose purpose it was to initialize my `queue_T` variables, this would be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in comments, you cannot perform function calls outside a function.  You cannot even execute assignment statements outside a function, though you can provide constant *initializers* for global variables, and the syntax resembles an assignment statement.  Initializers are not executable, however -- they are handled by the system outside the scope of program execution (which you can take as a reason for why you cannot perform function calls in them).

Presumably, function `new_queue()` both allocates a new `struct queue_T` and initializes it, then returns a pointer to the caller.  That's fine and useful, but what if you just want to initialize an existing `struct queue_T` structure?  Indeed, if you want to provide pre-initialized global objects of that type, such a facility is exactly what you need.  For example:

```
static struct queue_T primes_struct = { 0, NULL, NULL };
queue_T const primes = &primes_struct;
/* ... */
```

But writing a literal structure initializer like that is tedious and error-prone.  After all, what if the structure definition is changed after that code is written?  In fact, if you simply want to initialize all members of a `struct` to zero / NULL, the conventional form of the initialzer is just `{ 0 }` (a single element).  But even that can end up not being what you want under some modifications.

An alternative would be to have your `queue.h` declare a *macro* that can be used to initialize an empty `struct queue_T`, and use that everywhere (including in function `new_queue()`, so as to be certain the same initialization is performed everywhere).  Thus, somewhere in `queue.h` you might have ...

```
#define EMPTY_QUEUE { 0, NULL, NULL }
```

... and in `mathfns.c` you could do this:

```
static struct queue_T primes_struct = EMPTY_QUEUE;
queue_T const primes = &primes_struct;
```

That way, if ever you modify `struct queue_T`, you can make a corresponding change to the macro instead of modifying any code in source files that simply *use* that structure.

Comment: Thanks very much for the comprehensive answer! This helps a lot.